# How to add/remove local storage item for duration so modal toggles?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sweetalert

Goal is to remove local storage item after 24 hours, meaning show modal only once per day everyday. The local storage value is set. However, my condition to check if local storage item does not exist and 24 hours have passed then show modal is only half way working. I need it to expire the modal (not show) if the local storage value has been set for less than 24 hours. Currently, it is not removing the local storage item and showing the modal only once on load. If refresh page after time frame the local storage item is still there. Using Sweet Alert for modal, but that should not matter I don't think. Also not sure if I need a for loop or set time interval for this.

To make testing easier for a one minute duration you can also use:

```
 expires = expires.setMinutes(expires.getMinutes() + 1);
```

Here is what I tried:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      if (window.localStorage) {
        var currentUser = '<%= current_user %>';
        var swal_alert = localStorage.getItem('alert');
        var currentTime = new Date($.now());
        var expires = new Date();
        expires = expires.setHours(expires.getHours() + 24);
          if (currentUser && swal_alert !=1 && currentTime < expires) {
              swal ({
                  icon: 'warning',
                  text: 'Notice text here.',
                  closeOnClickOutside: false,
                  button: 'ok'
              })
          } else {
              localStorage.removeItem('alert');
          }

          localStorage.setItem('alert', '1');
      }
}
```

Comment: You can store the creation time itself in the local storage and then compare it to the current time.

Comment: I tried passing expired variable as a param where I setItem (where '1' is) but could not get it working. What would the condition look like? Sorry, could not get it working.

Comment: `tried passing expired variable as a param` where did you pass this "param"

Comment: what the heck is `new Date($.now());` - why not just `new Date()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are **always** running `localStorage.setItem('alert', '1');` at the end of your function. Even if your `else` clause is run, it is ineffective because you are re-setting the field right after.

Another thing to note is that your `expires` will always be greater than `currentTime`, because you defined `expires` as `currentTime + 24 hours`. `new Date()` just returns the current time.

One way to implement what you want is to store the timestamp of the last time the modal was shown, if it's less than 24 hours, don't show the modal, otherwise, show the modal and update the timestamp.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      if (window.localStorage) {
        const currentUser = '<%= current_user %>';
          if (currentUser && shouldShowModal()) {
              swal ({
                  icon: 'warning',
                  text: 'Notice text here.',
                  closeOnClickOutside: false,
                  button: 'ok'
              })
              localStorage.setItem('modalTimestamp', new Date().getTime());
          }
      }
}

function shouldShowModal() {
   const lastTimestamp = localStorage.getItem("modalTimestamp")
   if (!lastTimestamp) { // modal was never shown
     return true
   }
   const parsedTimestamp = parseInt(lastTimestamp, 10) // localStorage always store values in strings
   let expiryLimit = new Date(parsedTimestamp)
   expiryLimit = expiryLimit.setMinutes(expiryLimit.getMinutes() + 1) // or hours...
   return new Date() > expiryLimit
}
```

Another thing that I want to mention is that browsers do not provide APIs where you can "schedule" code like "do this after X hours". You do have `setTimeout` and `setInterval` functions, but they work as long the tab is active, and shouldn't be relied upon.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your solution. Did you mean to leave currentTime in setItem parameter? Or I think you forgot to include var currentTime = new Date($.now()); Trying to get this to work.

Comment: Sorry, I am getting the modal to pop up once with your code, but on refresh after a minute the modal does not appear and should. If I delete the local storage item and refresh then it repeats the same thing. This is the same result as I have working above. Not sure why.

Comment: Sorry, that was my mistake, I will edit the answer. In `setItem`, it should be `new Date().getTime()` which will return the timestamp. I don't know why you are using `$.now()` as an argument, but it's not necessary, `new Date()` already returns the current time. My guess of why it didn't work is that you forgot to call `getTime()` on the `setItem` date parameter, it's necessary because we are expecting a timestamp on `shouldShowModal` function.

Comment: Much appreciated. Marked as solution. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You want to show modal only once per day. So, you have to keep that time somewhere to track if 24 hours have already passed since the last modal display. Here is my approach without jquery (Snippets can't access localStorage so, it may run into trouble):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Alerts once per day</h1>
    </body>
    <script defer>
        function alertUser() {
            if (localStorage.getItem('alertTime') < new Date()) {
                alert('test');
                var nextAlert = new Date().setSeconds(new Date().getSeconds() + 10);
                localStorage.setItem('alertTime', nextAlert);
                console.log('avaiable');
            }
        }
        Window.onload = alertUser();
    </script>
</html>
```